# How to read captcha with tesseract -magickimage

Tags: imagemagick, ocr, tesseract, captcha

I'm having some issues reading a captcha image using ImageMagick - teserract.
Tried so many options and failed. Can this format actually be read [issueformat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBWyI.jpg)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The point of captcha's are to make it difficult for Computers to read, so it's natural to have *many* failed attempts.

However this example seems to lack enough entropy to halt any OCR. Use any combination of noise-reduction pre-processing techniques before passing to OCR engines.

For example: Drop colors (we don't need it), slightly blur & erode shapes together, and drop the outliner grays.

```
convert TBWyI.jpg -colorspace Gray \
        -blur 3x1  -morphology Erode Diamond \
        -level 20%  output.jpg
```

Which produces ...

[image: output.jpg]

And Tesseract is more than happy with that.

```sh
tesseract output.jpg stdout
#=> '6DEAV
```

Comment: Many thanks for your fast answer. Apparently, it's working, like 80-90 percent of the time but only with these options:

-colorspace Gray \ -blur 3x1 -morphology Erode Diamond \

If I 'm trying to add " -level 20%" this option, for some reasons is not processing anymore.

Thank you, Alex